# How to generate ipa in xocde 11?

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

I need t o update the existing app on appstore . So i need to generate ipa for this. I succesfully run the project now i need the ipa file .I read some where there is some option of export ipa in archive. But its not showing any option. Can any one please tell how can i export the ipa file of my project ? or can i update it from xcode?  Thanks
[image]

Comment: go to product and archive and follow instruction. https://appmanager.io/blog/tips-and-tricks/uploading-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store-updated/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why i ask this question but the answer of this question is easy " I just change the device to Generic IOS Device. As You can see in image i select Iphone 11 pro max on top . Here i need to select Generic ios device and then in product>Archive will show.